# CSS Calc weird error

Tags: css, less

I have an element that has the following `calc` rule:

```
width: calc(100% - 75px);
```

However, when inspecting in DevTools the element has the following rule instead:

```
width: calc(25%);
```

What is happening?

I'm running Chrome and LESS 1.4.2 (compilation is being done in the browser).

Comment: Can you post your full code? Are you sure you havent put - 75%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LESS will evaluate `100% - 75px` as `100 - 75` with units of `%`, which explains why you're getting the `25%` value in your compiled output.

If you need to pass values without having them interpreted, you'll need to use:

```
width: ~"calc(100% - 75px)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the value:

```
width: ~"calc(100% - 75px)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set it to 100%-75px. Are you sure the width of the identifier isn't 100px?

```
.thing {
    width: calc(100% - 75px);
}
```

i.e., 100px -75px giving 25px?

Comment: LESS tries to calculate it as a percentage at compile time.